# segfault calling CPython PyDateTime_FromTimestamp

Tags: python-2.7, v8, cpython, embedded-v8

I'm embedding cpython and v8 together and am getting a segfault when converting a javascript data to a `PyDateTime` via `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp`:

```
Handle<Date> date = Handle<Date>::Cast(value);
printf("%d\n", 8);
PyObject* floatObj = PyFloat_FromDouble(date->NumberValue());
printf("%d\n", 9);
printf("%d\n", floatObj);
PyObject* timeTuple = Py_BuildValue("(O)", floatObj);
Py_DECREF(floatObj);
printf("%d\n", 10);
PyObject* dateTime = PyDateTime_FromTimestamp(timeTuple);
printf("%d\n", 11);
Py_DECREF(timeTuple);
printf("%d\n", 12);
```

I get the following output when running:

```
8
9
14709864
10
[1]    33794 segmentation fault
```

Any insight on why `timeTuple` seems to cause `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp` to error?

Conversion of strings, numbers, booleans, arrays, dicts, etc, all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

It appears the `PyDateTime_IMPORT;` macro needs to be called from the same file in which you will be calling `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp`. I previously had called it in another file, directly after I was calling `Py_Initialize`.